# how to import image into java class

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to access an image file from the drawable folder; directly in my Java class. I have finally reached the point where my app will run, however it will not display the image. My Goal is to have the image display at the top of the screen; above the string "viewSelection". This is my code. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

String viewSelection[] = { "FirstView"};




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewSelection));

    ImageView imgView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    Drawable  drawable  = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);


}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String thelist = viewSelection[position];
    try{
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.java.notcoffee." + thelist);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



}
```

Comment: What is the value of `R.drawable.img`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the OnCreate method to fix it :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewSelection));

ImageView imgView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);

}
```

Comment: Im not using an xml file for this java class to reference, how would I findViewById?

Comment: *"Im not using an xml file for this java class to reference"*  If you're developing for Android, there are XML configuration files.  In fact, they will contain the value of `R.drawable.img` (as a `String`).  Are you developing using Eclipse?

Comment: i apologize, I meant layout. Yes I have xml files within the drawable folders. Yes I am also developing in eclipse.

Comment: currently the app runs like it should, just without the image.